# Papers on depth separations in neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-foundations

I am new to the domain of Machine learning. I have been asked to present a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06984) related to the mathematics behind the depth separations in Neural Networks (by Itay Safran, Ronen Eldan and Ohad Shamir). I have been having a hard time in understanding the paper.

I am looking for easy papers to learn the foundation so that I can move on to this paper. Please drop the link to any papers that you think I should read first.

Comment: Please, attach a link to the paper you are talking about.

Comment: Papers usually cite earlier work on similar topics. It should be in the introduction or in a section titled *related work*.

Comment: @VladislavBezhentsev ... http://proceedings.mlr.press/v99/safran19a/safran19a.pdf